# check whether a key exits in all objects in an array and set a Boolean value

Tags: javascript

check whether key exits in array of objects, if exists value not empty or undefined and set a boolean value.

```
let valid = false;
a = [{key: customer, setvalue: 'def'}, {key: customer, setvalue: 'abc'}]
valid = false;
a = [{key: customer, setvalue: 'abc'}, {key: customer}]
valid = true;
a = [{key: customer, setvalue: undefined}, {key: customer, setvalue:'abc'}]
valid = true;
```

Only if all the object has value for setvalue valid should be false else valid true, which has to be used for button disable, only if value are valid, button should be enabled

```
a.every(el => (el.hasOwnProperty('setvalue') || el?.setvalue !== '' || el?.setvalue !== undefined) ? valid = true : valid = false);
```

I tried with every but its value if false

Comment: Don't set the value of `valid` __in__ the `every` callback.

Comment: `hasKey = key => obj => key in obj; valid = arr.every(hasKey("whatever"))`

Comment: May I suggest a change of approach? It might save you some computation if you use `Array.prototype.some()` and check if there is at least one item that does not have the desired property or has it set to a falsy value

Comment: @secan what's the difference? `.every(isTrue)` is equivalent to `.some(isFalse)` in result and pretty much in operation, too.

Comment: @secan: `every` will shortcut at the first entry that returns `false`.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, you are right. Not really sure what I was thinking, sorry for the confusion I might have caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your assignment out of the `every` callback:

```
valid = a.every(el =>
    el?.hasOwnProperty('setvalue') &&
    el?.setvalue !== '' &&
    el?.setvalue !== undefined &&
    el?.setvalue !== null);
```

I also added the missing `null` check.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of `?` after `el`? Is it really necessary?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: Sure, [here's the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It's a bit of a safety net which may be redundant in this scenario.